# Choosing endpoint by proxy method

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have java interface:

```
public interface IMyService
{

   String method1(Document document) throws Exception;

   String method2(Document document) throws Exception;
}
```

I use it as camel proxy:

```
<camel:proxy id="myService"
             serviceInterface="pl.package.service.IMyService"
             serviceUrl="direct:myService"/>
```

in this route:

```
<route id="myRoute" autoStartup="true">
    <from uri="direct:myService"/>
    <process ref="postProcessor"/>
    <camel:to uri="apiEndpoint"/>
    <camel:process ref="responseProcessor"/>
</route>
```

now, how to choose different endpoints by IMyService method? For example:

```
        <route id="myRoute" autoStartup="true">
        <from uri="direct:myService"/>
        <process ref="postProcessor"/>
        if method == method1
            {
            <camel:to uri="apiEndpoint"/>
            }
            else
            {
            <camel:to uri="otherApiEndpoint"/>
            }

        <camel:process ref="responseProcessor"/>
    </route>
```

Answer (score 0):

The camel proxy is really just a way of a java bean calling an implementation that turns out to be camel making it look clean inside your bean instead of very messy.  You might want to have it call the route sending a body of a message indicating what operation you want and then using a choice.

```
from("direct:start")
    .choice()
        .when(body().isEqualTo("method1"))
            .to("my processing work")
        .when(body().isEqualTo("method2"))
            .to("my other processing work")
    .otherwise()
        .to("well no proper method was called");
```